# Box2d in Andengine - attaching child bodies - is it possible

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have a problem with Andengine Box2d Extension.

I have 2 rectangles: *base* and *fuelStation*.

***fuelStation*** is a child of base. When I'm rotating *base* with setTransform method, *fuelStation* sprite is rotating too, but body remains in the same position.

[image: Red - base, Cyan - child]

```
base = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - 200, 200, 200, vbom);
fuelStation = new Rectangle(base.getWidth() / 2, 0, 500, 10, vbom);

this.attachChild(base);
base.attachChild(fuelStation);

final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef1 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.0f, 0.5f);
final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef2 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.0f, 0.5f);

baseBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, base, BodyType.StaticBody, objectFixtureDef1);
baseBody.setUserData("base");

fuelStationBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, fuelStation, BodyType.KinematicBody, objectFixtureDef2);
fuelStationBody.setUserData("station");

physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(base, baseBody, true, true));
// physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(fuelStation, fuelStationBody,
// true, true));
```

When I remove comment from the last line - sprite position changes but still not working properly (body stands still).

How to connect properly these 2 bodies?

Comment: How you tested that body is not moving and sprite is moving?

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that all the transformations that you do to the entities (sprites) will only affect the "visual" content, in other words, will never affect the physic bodies. If you want to affect the entities and the bodies you will only achieve that by applying forces to the physic bodies and, because they are connected with a `PhysicsConnector`, those transformations will affect both the physic body and the the sprite ("visual body").
So, having the *fuelStating* as a child of *base* will affect nothing. To affect  two bodies you need a "connection" between them and you can achieve that by creating a joint that will connect the two bodies: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-overview

Hope it helps.